# CGAL python binding on Ubuntu

Tags: python, cgal

I am trying to compile CGAL python binding version 0.9.4 beta on Ubuntu but I am getting following error (truncated version of the installation log file):

```
/usr/include/boost/python/detail/invoke.hpp: In instantiation of ‘PyObject* boost::python::detail::invoke(boost::python::detail::invoke_tag_<false, true>, const RC&, F&, TC&, AC0&) [with RC = boost::python::detail::specify_a_return_value_policy_to_wrap_functions_returning<const CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt<CGAL::Gmpq>&>; F = const CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt<CGAL::Gmpq>& (CGAL::Iso_rectangle_2<CGAL::Epeck>::*)(int) const; TC = boost::python::arg_from_python<CGAL::Iso_rectangle_2<CGAL::Epeck>&>; AC0 = boost::python::arg_from_python<int>; PyObject = _object]’:
/usr/include/boost/python/detail/caller.hpp:223:13:   required from ‘PyObject* boost::python::detail::caller_arity<2u>::impl<F, Policies, Sig>::operator()(PyObject*, PyObject*) [with F = const CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt<CGAL::Gmpq>& (CGAL::Iso_rectangle_2<CGAL::Epeck>::*)(int) const; Policies = boost::python::default_call_policies; Sig = boost::mpl::vector3<const CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt<CGAL::Gmpq>&, CGAL::Iso_rectangle_2<CGAL::Epeck>&, int>; PyObject = _object]’
/usr/include/boost/python/object/py_function.hpp:38:33:   required from ‘PyObject* boost::python::objects::caller_py_function_impl<Caller>::operator()(PyObject*, PyObject*) [with Caller = boost::python::detail::caller<const CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt<CGAL::Gmpq>& (CGAL::Iso_rectangle_2<CGAL::Epeck>::*)(int) const, boost::python::default_call_policies, boost::mpl::vector3<const CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt<CGAL::Gmpq>&, CGAL::Iso_rectangle_2<CGAL::Epeck>&, int> >; PyObject = _object]’
bindings/Kernel/Py_global_functions_2.cpp:172:1:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/python/detail/invoke.hpp:88:90: error: no match for call to ‘(const boost::python::detail::specify_a_return_value_policy_to_wrap_functions_returning<const CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt<CGAL::Gmpq>&>) (const CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt<CGAL::Gmpq>&)’
     return rc( (tc().*f)(BOOST_PP_ENUM_BINARY_PARAMS_Z(1, N, ac, () BOOST_PP_INTERCEPT)) );
                                                                                          ^
In file included from /usr/include/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:47:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/detail/invoke.hpp:63,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/detail/caller.hpp:16,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/object/function_handle.hpp:8,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/converter/arg_to_python.hpp:19,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/call.hpp:15,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/object_core.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/args.hpp:25,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python.hpp:11,
                 from bindings/Kernel/Kernel_module.cpp:30,
                 from bindings/Kernel/All_files_at_once.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/python/detail/invoke.hpp: In instantiation of ‘PyObject* boost::python::detail::invoke(boost::python::detail::invoke_tag_<false, true>, const RC&, F&, TC&) [with RC = boost::python::detail::specify_a_return_value_policy_to_wrap_functions_returning<const CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt<CGAL::Gmpq>&>; F = const CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt<CGAL::Gmpq>& (CGAL::Iso_rectangle_2<CGAL::Epeck>::*)() const; TC = boost::python::arg_from_python<CGAL::Iso_rectangle_2<CGAL::Epeck>&>; PyObject = _object]’:
/usr/include/boost/python/detail/caller.hpp:223:13:   required from ‘PyObject* boost::python::detail::caller_arity<1u>::impl<F, Policies, Sig>::operator()(PyObject*, PyObject*) [with F = const CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt<CGAL::Gmpq>& (CGAL::Iso_rectangle_2<CGAL::Epeck>::*)() const; Policies = boost::python::default_call_policies; Sig = boost::mpl::vector2<const CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt<CGAL::Gmpq>&, CGAL::Iso_rectangle_2<CGAL::Epeck>&>; PyObject = _object]’
/usr/include/boost/python/object/py_function.hpp:38:33:   required from ‘PyObject* boost::python::objects::caller_py_function_impl<Caller>::operator()(PyObject*, PyObject*) [with Caller = boost::python::detail::caller<const CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt<CGAL::Gmpq>& (CGAL::Iso_rectangle_2<CGAL::Epeck>::*)() const, boost::python::default_call_policies, boost::mpl::vector2<const CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt<CGAL::Gmpq>&, CGAL::Iso_rectangle_2<CGAL::Epeck>&> >; PyObject = _object]’
bindings/Kernel/Py_global_functions_2.cpp:172:1:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/python/detail/invoke.hpp:88:90: error: no match for call to ‘(const boost::python::detail::specify_a_return_value_policy_to_wrap_functions_returning<const CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt<CGAL::Gmpq>&>) (const CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt<CGAL::Gmpq>&)’
     return rc( (tc().*f)(BOOST_PP_ENUM_BINARY_PARAMS_Z(1, N, ac, () BOOST_PP_INTERCEPT)) );
                                                                                          ^
/usr/include/boost/python/detail/invoke.hpp: In instantiation of ‘PyObject* boost::python::detail::invoke(boost::python::detail::invoke_tag_<false, true>, const RC&, F&, TC&) [with RC = boost::python::detail::specify_a_return_value_policy_to_wrap_functions_returning<const CGAL::Point_2<CGAL::Epeck>&>; F = const CGAL::Point_2<CGAL::Epeck>& (CGAL::Iso_rectangle_2<CGAL::Epeck>::*)() const; TC = boost::python::arg_from_python<CGAL::Iso_rectangle_2<CGAL::Epeck>&>; PyObject = _object]’:
/usr/include/boost/python/detail/caller.hpp:223:13:   required from ‘PyObject* boost::python::detail::caller_arity<1u>::impl<F, Policies, Sig>::operator()(PyObject*, PyObject*) [with F = const CGAL::Point_2<CGAL::Epeck>& (CGAL::Iso_rectangle_2<CGAL::Epeck>::*)() const; Policies = boost::python::default_call_policies; Sig = boost::mpl::vector2<const CGAL::Point_2<CGAL::Epeck>&, CGAL::Iso_rectangle_2<CGAL::Epeck>&>; PyObject = _object]’
/usr/include/boost/python/object/py_function.hpp:38:33:   required from ‘PyObject* boost::python::objects::caller_py_function_impl<Caller>::operator()(PyObject*, PyObject*) [with Caller = boost::python::detail::caller<const CGAL::Point_2<CGAL::Epeck>& (CGAL::Iso_rectangle_2<CGAL::Epeck>::*)() const, boost::python::default_call_policies, boost::mpl::vector2<const CGAL::Point_2<CGAL::Epeck>&, CGAL::Iso_rectangle_2<CGAL::Epeck>&> >; PyObject = _object]’
bindings/Kernel/Py_global_functions_2.cpp:172:1:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/python/detail/invoke.hpp:88:90: error: no match for call to ‘(const boost::python::detail::specify_a_return_value_policy_to_wrap_functions_returning<const CGAL::Point_2<CGAL::Epeck>&>) (const CGAL::Point_2<CGAL::Epeck>&)’
In file included from /usr/include/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:52:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/detail/invoke.hpp:63,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/detail/caller.hpp:16,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/object/function_handle.hpp:8,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/converter/arg_to_python.hpp:19,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/call.hpp:15,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/object_core.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/args.hpp:25,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python.hpp:11,
                 from bindings/Kernel/Kernel_module.cpp:30,
                 from bindings/Kernel/All_files_at_once.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/python/detail/invoke.hpp: In instantiation of ‘PyObject* boost::python::detail::invoke(boost::python::detail::invoke_tag_<false, true>, const RC&, F&, TC&, AC0&) [with RC = boost::python::detail::specify_a_return_value_policy_to_wrap_functions_returning<const CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt<CGAL::Gmpq>&>; F = const CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt<CGAL::Gmpq>& (CGAL::Direction_2<CGAL::Epeck>::*)(int) const; TC = boost::python::arg_from_python<CGAL::Direction_2<CGAL::Epeck>&>; AC0 = boost::python::arg_from_python<int>; PyObject = _object]’:
/usr/include/boost/python/detail/caller.hpp:223:13:   required from ‘PyObject* boost::python::detail::caller_arity<2u>::impl<F, Policies, Sig>::operator()(PyObject*, PyObject*) [with F = const CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt<CGAL::Gmpq>& (CGAL::Direction_2<CGAL::Epeck>::*)(int) const; Policies = boost::python::default_call_policies; Sig = boost::mpl::vector3<const CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt<CGAL::Gmpq>&, CGAL::Direction_2<CGAL::Epeck>&, int>; PyObject = _object]’
/usr/include/boost/python/object/py_function.hpp:38:33:   required from ‘PyObject* boost::python::objects::caller_py_function_impl<Caller>::operator()(PyObject*, PyObject*) [with Caller = boost::python::detail::caller<const CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt<CGAL::Gmpq>& (CGAL::Direction_2<CGAL::Epeck>::*)(int) const, boost::python::default_call_policies, boost::mpl::vector3<const CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt<CGAL::Gmpq>&, CGAL::Direction_2<CGAL::Epeck>&, int> >; PyObject = _object]’
bindings/Kernel/Py_global_functions_2.cpp:172:1:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/python/detail/invoke.hpp:88:90: error: no match for call to ‘(const boost::python::detail::specify_a_return_value_policy_to_wrap_functions_returning<const CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt<CGAL::Gmpq>&>) (const CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt<CGAL::Gmpq>&)’
     return rc( (tc().*f)(BOOST_PP_ENUM_BINARY_PARAMS_Z(1, N, ac, () BOOST_PP_INTERCEPT)) );
                                                                                          ^
In file included from /usr/include/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:47:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/detail/invoke.hpp:63,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/detail/caller.hpp:16,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/object/function_handle.hpp:8,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/converter/arg_to_python.hpp:19,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/call.hpp:15,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/object_core.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/args.hpp:25,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python.hpp:11,
                 from bindings/Kernel/Kernel_module.cpp:30,
                 from bindings/Kernel/All_files_at_once.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/python/detail/invoke.hpp: In instantiation of ‘PyObject* boost::python::detail::invoke(boost::python::detail::invoke_tag_<false, true>, const RC&, F&, TC&) [with RC = boost::python::detail::specify_a_return_value_policy_to_wrap_functions_returning<const CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt<CGAL::Gmpq>&>; F = const CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt<CGAL::Gmpq>& (CGAL::Direction_2<CGAL::Epeck>::*)() const; TC = boost::python::arg_from_python<CGAL::Direction_2<CGAL::Epeck>&>; PyObject = _object]’:
/usr/include/boost/python/detail/caller.hpp:223:13:   required from ‘PyObject* boost::python::detail::caller_arity<1u>::impl<F, Policies, Sig>::operator()(PyObject*, PyObject*) [with F = const CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt<CGAL::Gmpq>& (CGAL::Direction_2<CGAL::Epeck>::*)() const; Policies = boost::python::default_call_policies; Sig = boost::mpl::vector2<const CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt<CGAL::Gmpq>&, CGAL::Direction_2<CGAL::Epeck>&>; PyObject = _object]’
/usr/include/boost/python/object/py_function.hpp:38:33:   required from ‘PyObject* boost::python::objects::caller_py_function_impl<Caller>::operator()(PyObject*, PyObject*) [with Caller = boost::python::detail::caller<const CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt<CGAL::Gmpq>& (CGAL::Direction_2<CGAL::Epeck>::*)() const, boost::python::default_call_policies, boost::mpl::vector2<const CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt<CGAL::Gmpq>&, CGAL::Direction_2<CGAL::Epeck>&> >; PyObject = _object]’
bindings/Kernel/Py_global_functions_2.cpp:172:1:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/python/detail/invoke.hpp:88:90: error: no match for call to ‘(const boost::python::detail::specify_a_return_value_policy_to_wrap_functions_returning<const CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt<CGAL::Gmpq>&>) (const CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt<CGAL::Gmpq>&)’
     return rc( (tc().*f)(BOOST_PP_ENUM_BINARY_PARAMS_Z(1, N, ac, () BOOST_PP_INTERCEPT)) );
                                                                                          ^
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Could you please help me figure out how to debug this.